# delete multiple specific local user accounts from servers

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to write a VBScript to delete specific user account from server. 
If in server found the users "adm" and/or "ame" the script should delete them and also print the result whether the deletion was successful or not.

Below is the script which I tried writing and I am getting an error. Can anyone help me to correct this?

```
Dim disuser, objNetwork, strComputer, objComputer

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName
Set objComputer = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer)
On Error Resume Next

For Each disuser In "adm  ame"
  Call objComputer.Delete("user", disuser)
  On Error GoTo 0
Next
'On Error res="fail"
```

Comment: We might be able to help you, but you haven't told us what the error is.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass multiple usernames as a list this is fine, but to enumerate them using a `For Each` they need to be enumerable in other words an object that supports enumeration like an `Array` or `Collection`.

```
Dim disuser, objNetwork, strComputer, objComputer

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName
Set objComputer = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer)
On Error Resume Next

'Split list of space delimited usernames into an Array.
Dim list: list = Split("adm  ame", Chr(32))

For Each disuser In list
  'Clear previous error before checking if the Delete works.
  Call Err.Clear()
  Call objComputer.Delete("user", disuser)
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    'Was successful do something
  Else
    'Failed do something
  End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0
'On Error res="fail"
```

Comment: Note that if you have a static list of usernames it's simpler to define them as an array right away: `list = Array("adm", "ame")`. Splitting a string usually only makes sense if you get the list as a string from somewhere else.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers absolutely the assumption I'm making here is they are passing a space delimited string into the script, but if just defining the values in code then `Array("adm", "ame")` makes much more sense.

Comment: currently I am geting an error like this. Is this bcz do not have array for for each ?   C:\Users\snair\Desktop\Test.vbs(12, 3) Active Directory: An invalid directory pathname was passed

Comment: @SNair not sure what that is, just tried it myself an get no error using `cscript.exe`, does the computer have a weird name that needs to be escaped perhaps when used with `GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer)` perhaps?

Comment: @SNair If I run it without `On Error Resume Next` I get `Active Directory: The user name could not be found.` which I'd expect as I don't have a local user called `adm` or `ame`.

Comment: @SNair I've made some suggestions and it works on my Windows 10 machine so apart from reading your mind there isn't much else I can do without more information. Sorry.

Comment: Actaullt the script I am looking for is to delete multiple specific user accounts. If the specific user accounts name adm, ame exist then it should delete. When i give script like below if the user account exist it works fine,but when these user account not exist it giver error "The user name could not be found." and the script fails

Comment: Dim strUser, objNetwork,objComputer
strUser = "adm"
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName
Set objComputer = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer)
Call objComputer.Delete("user", strUser)
On Error GoTo 0

strUser = "ame"
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName
Set objComputer = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer)
Call objComputer.Delete("user", strUser)
On Error GoTo 0

Comment: @SNair that isn't the same as the script in the answer where is the `On Error Resume Next`? You need this to allow the script to skip when there is an error and use `If Err.Number = 0 Then` to handle any errors and allow the script to continue processing. Also please don't add code into comments it isn't very readable, instead [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36621906/edit) and add the code.